# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" on the console log note that the code I use is work great on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/679JJ/) but not in my blog

[blog url](http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/)

the JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.widget-content').each(function(){
        var hg = $(this).html(),
            qsqs = hg.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
            alert(qsqs[0]);
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(qsqs, hg);`

Comment: can you see what's happen after I add your code [Blog](http://test-khamsat-support-gig.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Yes, I see that you're making wrong assumptions. If you checked `console.log` for your blog code (or used a debugger) - you could see it as well.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you, I forgot to check if the code exist before I executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have another div with the class widget-content and it's causing the jquery selector to run in both.

Example

```
<div class="widget-content">
    [2][Sport][Two]
</div>
<div class="widget-content">
    .
</div>
```

Here's the Fiddle updated so you can see the error clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/679JJ/1/

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to check if the code exist before I executing it.